# Multiple variable exercise related to Divergence theorem

Tags: calculus, divergence-theorem

Could anyone help me with this exercise? In this subject we are studying integration over surfaces and volumes, 1 and 2-forms and theorems such as Green-Riemann and Gauss-Ostrogradsky, so as Stokes. Yet this formula looks kinda similar to Gauss-Ostrogradsky, I am not able to demonstrate it. 
Thanks in advance.

Let  $D \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ be a compact with $C^1$ boundary and let $f$ be a  $C^1$ scalar function defined on $D$.  Prove that:

$$
 \iint_{\partial D} f \mathrm{d}\overrightarrow{S} = \iiint _D \nabla f\mathrm{d}V.
$$

Comment: Ever see Goursat's proof of Cauchy's theorem? This is pretty similar. Break $D$ into the union of many small domains, so small that $f$ is approximately linear on each. Note that by cancellation the surface integral on $\partial D$ is the sum of the surface integrals over all the small domains, just as the volume integral is the sum of the volume integrals on the small domains.

Comment: I think you meant ∬d→=∭∇ ·d. Instead of the gradient of $f$, it should be divergence of $f$.